# Marquee Select in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, selection, wxwidgets

I am trying to implement a marquee select feature for an image in wxWidgets. The user should be able to draw a rectangle on an image to get the coordinates of the image that the user selected in the rectangle.

I want something similar to whats here: http://wxwidgets.info/getting_aquainted_with_doc_view_architecture_part_3_en/

But looking for a simpler example.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd expect that the key to this is capturing wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN to register one corner of the rectangle, wxEVT_MOTION to update the drawn rectangle and wxEVT_LEFT_UP to do the zooming. - Which part exactly is the problem?